# Log a request with bunyan

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, bunyan

I building an app with node.js and express. I have started using `bunyan` but I am having a hard time understanding hot to log requests.

Say that my router calls a function like this:

```
function(request, someOtherStuff, done){\\do something}
```

where `request` is generated from a POST request, and has some stuff in `request.body`.

I would like to do the following: when an error occurs inside the function I would like to log the error, as well as the request (including the `req.body`) from the user. Something like:

```
if(err) {
  bunyan.error(err,request);
  done(err);
}
```

I know I can use `serializers: {req: reqSerializer}` in the bunyan configuration, but I could not find any examples where a request is actually logged.

*Any suggestion is highly appreciated*.

Answer (score 6):

The way I've implemented is to add a handler in app.js like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    log.info(reqSerializer(req));
    next();
});
```

The reqSerializer function then contains what you would like to return, e.g.

```
function reqSerializer(req) {
   return {
        method: req.method,
        url: req.url,
        headers: req.headers,
        somethingCustom: ...,
    }
}
```

Also make sure the reqSerializer is included when you initialise the logger, e.g

```
var log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'myapp',
    serializers: {
        req: reqSerializer
    },
}
```

So all the serializer does is serialize the req object, you still need to actually pass it to the logger for it to be logged.

Answer (score 3):

What the serializer does is make sure that if you pass a field named "req" when writing a log record, it will be properly formatted.

So, once you have that serializer, you might log an error with a request simply by calling:

```
logger.error({ req: request, err: err }, "Optionally, some message");
```

Where `logger` is the result of calling `bunyan.createLogger` with some parameters.

You might also want to look into something like [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) that's specifically designed for logging requests, or perhaps [bunyan-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan-request) if you're looking for something more structured.

(And by the way, I hope in your question when you wrote `{req: reqSerializer}` you meant `{req: bunyan.stdSerializers.req}`.)